# Solving general (dis)entanglement puzzles

Tags: algorithms, puzzle, computational-geometry

What is the state of the art in (modelling and) solving a general [(dis)entanglement puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disentanglement_puzzle)?

The following picture shows a nice example:

[image]

There is a project called ["The Untangler"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/untangler), which seems to be abandoned, though.

Comment: [*Computational Complexity of Cast Puzzles*](https://books.google.de/books?id=48lqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=%22computational+complexity+of+cast+puzzles%22&source=bl&ots=pGPQ8iohJE&sig=w8XgPQf-62L8sRrXUxXpkDnZnrA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYxIWT_PzJAhXl8XIKHXBDA5EQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22computational%20complexity%20of%20cast%20puzzles%22&f=false) (Iwamoto, Sasaki, Nishio, Morita) might be relevant.

Comment: [This AI Makes Puzzle Solving Look Easy!  (Two Minute Papers)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWu0AWdaTTs)